# Wrapping Data Table in a container to avoid scrolling in app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a couple of `DT` outputs in my app, from the `DT` package., there's a comparison section which renders 2 `DT` outputs. Even a single `DT` has enough data in 1 page for the `DT` to need vertical scrolling, and in some cases, it also stretches on the X axis and this leads to the whole app having horizontal scrolling, which leads to a very poor user experience.

I was wondering if there was a way to wrap the `DT` in a container, set a max height and width and also to enable scrolling **in the container itself**, to prevent scrolling in the App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need? The scroll bars are only added if needed, allowing you to put this into a fluid layout (e.g., shiny).

```r
library(DT)
mydat <- cbind(iris, iris, iris)
datatable(mydat, filter = 'bottom', fillContainer = TRUE)
```

[image: datatable on triple-wide iris, with scrollbars]

The required component is `fillContainer=TRUE`.

Comment: Yup thats exactly what I need. Is this in the server `renderDT` or in the UI?

Comment: I managed to set it up, on the server function. Where can I find more options like this? I tried checking for documentation for DT but couldn't find it.

Also, I'm running into the issue that it's only fitting 1 row. Is there a way to change the dimension?

Comment: `DT` is a slightly-weird beast in that you need to know the javascript side of things (https://datatables.net/) to know what to apply to the R veneer known as `DT` (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/). The R package doesn't (shouldn't?) try to document everything the JS side lets you do, instead demonstrates some of the options/plugins and leaves it to you to attempt to put them in roughly the same places (e.g., `options=list(...)`). It's imperfect. I'm not a guru on shaping it, though, sry.